# what to do with user only advertising Megaventory

Tags: discussion

I came across the user https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/17088/dimitris-verdelis whos answers all "advertise" Megaventory.

Iam not sure what to do about him, as most cases seem to be a valid answer to the question/problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for spotting this.
Even if sometimes his answers might solve the problem, all his answers were only to self-promote. This is wrong.
I deleted the answers (all except on that was accepted by the OP).
And I contacted him for excessive self-promotion.